# Copy a cell from all worksheets in another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to copy a Cell from all worksheet but "Data" Worksheet on column C of "Data Worksheet". The following code is not working properly, always blank value. The value I would like to copy is placed on E16 Cell.

```
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Data" Then
        x = x + 1
        Sheets("Data").Range("B1").Offset(x) = Worksheets(ws.Name).Cells(4, 16).Value
    End If
Next ws
```

Comment: If you want the value in E16 then that is `Cells(16, 5)`, not `Cells(4, 16)`

Comment: On a side-note, exploit the fact that `Worksheet(ws.Name)` is the same as `ws`. BTW, where is this code located? If it's located in the workbook containing the `Data` worksheet, you should use `ThisWorkbook` instead of `ActiveWorkbook`. Anyway, you would want to qualify the `Data` worksheet, best by implementing a workbook variable i.e. `Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ActiveWorkbook`, `... In wb.Worksheets`, `... wb.Worksheets("Data")... = ws.Cells...`.

Answer (score 1):

Try it that Way, without coping every value by it's own:

```
Sub m()
vartemp2 = Range("A1:A2")
vartemp2 = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vartemp2)
    Dim varTemp As Variant
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Data" Then
            If i = 0 Then
                ReDim varTemp(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
                i = 1
            Else
                varTemp = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(varTemp)
                ReDim Preserve varTemp(1 To UBound(varTemp) + 1)
                varTemp = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(varTemp)
            End If
            varTemp(UBound(varTemp), 1) = ws.Cells(16, 5).Value
        End If
    Next ws
    
    With Worksheets("Data")
        .Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(UBound(varTemp), 2)).Value = varTemp
    End With
End Sub
```

BTW: On your code, 4 is column D not E. Columns start with 1 on counting and the defintion is Cells(RowNumber, ColumnNumber) :)

Comment: If I try with your code, I always get error 9. And the worksheet "Data" is well written. :/

Comment: where do you get the error? on which line

Comment: After a couple of loop into "If" line 10

Comment: Well, my mistake there. I was a bit slow on the uptake with the array dimension there. Updated my answer, please try again, should work now. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

### Copy Single Cell's Value From All Other Worksheets

**Compact**

```vb
Sub CopySingleCellValuesCompact()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ActiveWorkbook ' possibly use 'ThisWorkbook'
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets("Data")
    Dim dCell As Range: Set dCell = dws.Range("B1")
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet
    Dim sCell As Range
    
    For Each sws In wb.Worksheets
        If Not sws Is dws Then
            Set sCell = ws.Range("E16")
            Set dCell = dCell.Offset(1)
            dCell.Value = sCell.Value
        End If
    Next sws

End Sub
```

**Argumented**

Now, to get rid of the magic numbers, you could create a method...

```vb
Sub CopySingleCellValues( _
        ByVal wb As Workbook, _
        ByVal DestinationWorksheetName As String, _
        ByVal DestinationLastCellAddress As String, _
        ByVal SourceCellAddress As String)

    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(DestinationWorksheetName)
    Dim dCell As Range: Set dCell = dws.Range(DestinationLastCellAddress)
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet
    Dim sCell As Range
    
    For Each sws In wb.Worksheets
        If Not sws Is dws Then
            Set sCell = ws.Range(SourceCellAddress)
            Set dCell = dCell.Offset(1)
            dCell.Value = sCell.Value
        End If
    Next sws

End Sub
```

**Usage**

... and in your code, use it in the following way:

```vb
Sub MyCode()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ActiveWorkbook ' possibly use 'ThisWorkbook'
    CopySingleCellValues wb, "Data", "B1", "E16"

End Sub
```

... and keep your code clean as a whistle.
It reads something like: in the given workbook, from all worksheets except worksheet `Data`, copy the value from cell `E16` to worksheet `Data`, one below the other, starting with the first cell below `B1`.